# How to use "nullable" in vb.net using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I can't resolve my problem.
My problem is that I can't convert to Decimal to nullable.

I tried to something...
But i failed to find solution.

please help me.

```
> Dim data = From row1 In dt1.AsEnumerable()
>                    Join row2 In dt2.AsEnumerable()
>            On row1.Field(Of String)("BND_ID") Equals row2.Field(Of String)("BND_ID")
>                    Where ( row1.Field(Of Nullable)("UST_YTM").Equals(row2.Field(Of Nullable)("UST_YTM")) =
> False And 
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("CRT_UST_YTM").Equals(row2.Field(Of
> Nullable)("CRT_UST_YTM")) = False And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("ISSU_ORG_NM") <> row2.Field(Of String)("ISSU_ORG_NM") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("PRC_CALC_DT") <> row2.Field(Of String)("PRC_CALC_DT") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("IS_HOLI") <> row2.Field(Of String)("IS_HOLI") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("ISSU_DT") <> row2.Field(Of String)("ISSU_DT") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("EXR_DT") <> row2.Field(Of String)("EXR_DT") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("TERM") <> row2.Field(Of String)("TERM") And 
>                        row1.Field(Of String)("CRT_TERM") <> row2.Field(Of String)("CRT_TERM") And
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("CPN_RT").Equals(row2.Field(Of Nullable)("CPN_RT")) = False 
> And
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("BLM_ISSU_SP").Equals(row2.Field(Of
> Nullable)("BLM_ISSU_SP")) = False And
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("BLM_ROFR_SP").Equals(row2.Field(Of
> Nullable)("BLM_ROFR_SP")) = False And
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("NICE_SP").Equals(row2.Field(Of Nullable)("NICE_SP")) =
> False And
>                        row1.Field(Of Nullable)("ISSU_SP").Equals(row2.Field(Of Nullable)("ISSU_SP")) =
> False )            
>                    Select New With {.BND_ID = row1.Field(Of String)("BND_ID"),
>                                     .UST_YTM = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("UST_YTM"),
>                                     .CRT_UST_YTM = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("CRT_UST_YTM"),
>                                     .ISSU_ORG_NM = row1.Field(Of String)("ISSU_ORG_NM"),
>                                     .PRC_CALC_DT = row1.Field(Of String)("PRC_CALC_DT"),
>                                     .IS_HOLI = row1.Field(Of String)("IS_HOLI"),
>                                     .ISSU_DT = row1.Field(Of String)("ISSU_DT"),
>                                     .EXR_DT = row1.Field(Of String)("EXR_DT"),
>                                     .TERM = row1.Field(Of String)("TERM"),
>                                     .CRT_TERM = row1.Field(Of Decimal)("CRT_TERM"),
>                                     .CPN_RT = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("CPN_RT"),
>                                     .BLM_ISSU_SP = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("BLM_ISSU_SP"),
>                                     .BLM_ROFR_SP = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("BLM_ROFR_SP"),
>                                     .NICE_SP = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("NICE_SP"),
>                                     .ISSU_SP = row1.Field(Of Nullable)("ISSU_SP")}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfumI.png)

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Explain in detail EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve and EXACTLY what happens. Don't expect us to work it out from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would be using `Field(Of Nullable)` in the first place. If you have a database column that contains `Decimal` values and the column is nullable then sure you should be using `Field(Of Decimal?)`, which is shorthand for `Field(Of Nullable(Of Decimal))`.